# How to update OptionsMenu values Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

**I have this code:**

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import glob
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

tkvar = StringVar()

# Directory
directory = "C:/Users/label/Desktop/test folder/"
choices = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, "*jpg")) # all choices ending with .jpg in the directory above

# Images, placing the image onto canvas
def change_dropdown():
    imgpath = tkvar.get()
    img = Image.open(imgpath)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    label2.image = photo
    label2.configure(image=photo)

#widgets
msg1 = Label(root, text = "Choose here")
msg1.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
popupMenu = OptionMenu(root, tkvar, *choices) #Dropdown menu of all sign off Sheets that need signing
popupMenu.grid(row=1, column=0)
display_label = label2 = Label(root, image=None)
display_label.grid(row=2, column=0, rowspan = 200)
open_button = Button(root, text="Open", command=change_dropdown) # opens the directory and opens selected image
open_button.grid(row=20, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

**What it does:**

It's a simple app that allows me to click a directory and open the image.

**My issue:**

If I remove one of the `.jpg` files from the folder, how can I update the optionMenu values to match the current folder? Because If I remove a file when running the script, option menu does not update automatically

**Here is a code I have tried from [Updating OptionMenu from List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28412496/updating-optionmenu-from-list)** but this does not update anything..

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import glob
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

tkvar = StringVar()

# Directory
directory = "C:/Users/label/Desktop/test folder/"
choices = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, "*jpg")) # all choices ending with - to sign.jpg in the directory above
tkvar.set('...To Sign Off...') # set the default option

# Images, placing the image onto canvas
def change_dropdown():
    imgpath = tkvar.get()
    img = Image.open(imgpath)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    label2.image = photo
    label2.configure(image=photo)

#widgets
msg1 = Label(root, text = "Choose here")
msg1.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
popupMenu = OptionMenu(root, tkvar, *choices) #Dropdown menu of all sign off Sheets that need signing
popupMenu.grid(row=1, column=0)
display_label = label2 = Label(root, image=None)
display_label.grid(row=2, column=0, rowspan = 500)
open_button = Button(root, text="Open", command=change_dropdown) # opens the directory and opens selected image
open_button.grid(row=502, column=0)

def update_option_menu():
    menu = popupMenu["menu"]
    menu.delete(0, "end")
    for string in choices:
        menu.add_command(label=string,
                         command=lambda value=string: tkvar.set(value))

update_button = Button(root, text='Update option menu', command=update_option_menu)
update_button.grid(column=0, row=2)




root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating OptionMenu from List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28412496/updating-optionmenu-from-list)

Comment: ***"does not update anything"***: You are using the same `choices`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe by just calling an `after()` function to refresh the list. So something like:

EDIT: Removed the optional `command` to `tk._setit()` because that actually causes the `change_dropdown()` to fail as it doesn't have any parameters, and realized to constantly refresh you want to call this recursively.

```
def refresh_list():
    new_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, "*jpg"))

    # update the option menu
    popupMenu['menu'].delete(0, 'end')
    for item in new_list:
        popupMenu['menu'].add_command(label=item, command=tk._setit(tkvar, item)
    # Keep refreshing
    root.after(10, refresh_list)

...
# Initial call to refresh
root.after(10, refresh_list)
```

I haven't test it, but the idea is to use the `refresh_list()` function to check the directory files, delete the current item options, and add the new item options with the same command to set your `tk.StringVar()`, the label on the dropdown, and the command that gets executed on click to remain the same (`change_dropdown`).

Comment: Start an interpreter, import tkinter, and type help(tk._setit). But, there's a `command` optional parameter on the `OptionMenu` that has a callback which has an added parameter `value` that is the option the User selected from the dropdown. So, the `tk._setit` is "Internal class. It wraps the command in the widget OptionMenu.". Also, by looking at this, you're button is what calls change_dropdown, so you might want to remove the `change_dropdown` from the `tk._setit`.

Comment: I have added a button, set command to `refresh_list` now it works!

Comment: I updated the answer, you should realize that I introduced a bug accidentally :/ but it should work now :)