# How to swap values in optionmenu tkinter python?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, root, optionmenu

How can i change values ​​in optionmenu when i press the "change" button?

Here is the code that I wrote so far:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

options =[
"eggs","meat","chicken",
"potato"
]

variable1 = tk.StringVar()
variable1.set(options[0])

om1 = tk.OptionMenu(root,variable1,*options)
om1.pack()


variable2 = tk.StringVar()
variable2.set(options[0])

om2 = tk.OptionMenu(root,variable2,*options)
om2.pack()

button_change = tk.Button(root,text="change")
button_change.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

please help...

Comment: What _exactly_ do you want to have happen when you click the button?

Comment: I want it to change, for example, I have an egg and a potato and then I press the button and I have a potato and an egg and I want it to show up on optionmenu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating OptionMenu from List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28412496/updating-optionmenu-from-list)

Comment: I want the values ​​in the optionmenus to be swaped when I press the button. One is the egg and the other is the potato and when I press the button it swaps the place between the optiomenus.

Answer (score 0):

You can swap the values of the two `OptionMenu` via their associated variables:

```
def swap_options():
    # save the value of first OptionMenu
    opt1 = variable1.get()
    # set the value of first OptionMenu to that of second OptionMenu
    variable1.set(variable2.get())
    # set the value of second OptionMenu to the saved value of first OptionMenu
    variable2.set(opt1)

button_change = tk.Button(root, text="change", command=swap_options)
```