# Update OptionMenu after .txt file is closed

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to get my OptionMenu's to change once I make changes to the .txt file. I can restart the program and it be there but I don't want to have to restart if I make a change. I know I can change the optionmenu if the other optionmenu changes but I don't know how to do it if the outside file changes. https://www.dropbox.com/s/yvlqstof81o3t4z/Panels.txt?dl=0

```
import tkinter as tk
import re
root = tk.Tk()
panels = []
with open("Panels.txt") as panelfile:
    for line in panelfile:
        panellist = re.findall("'([^']*)'", line)
        panels.extend(panellist)

wallpanelindex = panels.index('@Wall')
roofpanelindex = panels.index('@Roof')

wallpanellist = panels[(wallpanelindex+1):roofpanelindex]  # Wall list
roofpanellist = panels[(roofpanelindex+1):]  # Roof List
panel_type1 = wallpanellist[::3]  # Wall Panel
panel_type2 = roofpanellist[::3]  # Roof Panel
panel_width = roofpanellist[1::3]  #Roof Panel Width
roofpaneldesc = roofpanellist[2::3]  # Wall Panel Description



panel1 = tk.StringVar()  # Wall Panel
panel1.set(panel_type1[1])  # Set Default
panel2 = tk.StringVar()  # Roof Panel
panel2.set(panel_type2[1])  # Set Default

def panels():
    from os import startfile
    startfile(<<File Location>>Panels.txt)

def prnt(): 
    print(panel_type2[panel_type2.index(panel2.get())], panel_width[panel_type2.index(panel2.get())], wallpaneldesc[panel_type2.index(panel2.get())])

mpanelwall = tk.OptionMenu(root, panel1, *panel_type1)
mpanelroof = tk.OptionMenu(root, panel2, *panel_type2)

mpanelwall.place(y=50)
mpanelroof.place(y=80)

btn3 = tk.Button(root, text="Panels", command=panels)
btn3.place(y=110)  # Panel

btn10 = tk.Button(root, text="Print", command=prnt)
btn10.place(y=140)  # Panel



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Read [updating-optionmenu-from-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28412496)

Comment: doesn't really help cause I don't want buttons all over the place but ok...

Comment: ***I don't want buttons***: Why do you think you have to use a `Button`?