# How to populate combobox with tuple

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

Trying to populate my `tkinter Combobox` with record from tuple but when i run the below code i get the output like this `felixdanben` and when i iterate over it like this `for row in rows[1]` only `dan` is inserted in the `Combobox`

When i print the `row` it gives the correct values like`dan, ben, felix` 
but not able insert in the `Combobox`

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


rows = ("felix"),("dan"), ("ben")

root = Tk()

cb = ttk.Combobox(root)

for row in rows:
    cb.insert(END, row)
cb.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide the result of `print(repr(rows))` we haven't access to your database.

Comment: it print like my print function there `('felix',)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update values to the listbox under Combobox in ttk Python33](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906047/how-to-update-values-to-the-listbox-under-combobox-in-ttk-python33)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
for row in rows:
    cb.insert(END, row)
```

with:

```
cache = list()
for row in rows:
    cache.append(row)
cb['values'] = cache
```

Since `ttk.Combobox`, in fact, inherits from `tk.Entry` the `insert` method makes you populate the 'entry part' of the widget, so it's not what you think it is, or the data you're getting are not what you think they are.