# ttk.Optionmenu documentation

Tags: tkinter, ttk, optionmenu

Would someone point toward complete documentation on ttk.Optionmenu.  I have located many examples of ttk.Optionmenu usage.  With the examples and experimentation I have been able to make ttk.Optionmenu do what I want it to do.  However, it would be nice to see complete documentation on this widget.

Comment: You can actually also find a small explanation at the `__init__.py` at path  `Python3.x > lib > tkinter > __init__.py` file, `class OptionMenu(Menubutton):` line 3444

Comment: Have you tried `print(help(ttk.OptionMenu))`? The documentation is available right there in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I tried your suggestion and was able to get a better idea of the class.  A little information is better than no information.

Answer (score 3):

As for all Tk widgets, the complete documentation is written for the [Tk library](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/contents.htm) itself. The [tk_optionMenu](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/optionMenu.htm) entry is very short. The Tkinter ttk.OptionMenu is really [ttk::menubutton](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_menubutton.htm) in the Tk documentation.

For Tkinter there is less documentation for [OptionMenu](https://web.archive.org/web/20201113091416id_/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/optionmenu.htm) but you should consider using [Combobox](https://tkdocs.com/widgets/combobox.html) anyway as it is a more modern looking UI style.

Comment: I would agree simply because I have not been able to find sufficient documentation for OptionMenu while Combobox was straightforward. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906047/how-to-update-values-to-the-listbox-under-combobox-in-ttk-python33

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, here's the current documentation obtained via `print(help(ttk.OptionMenu))` as @Bryan Oakley [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63456078/ttk-optionmenu-documentation#comment112342972_63456078).

```
Help on class OptionMenu in module tkinter.ttk:

class OptionMenu(Menubutton)

  OptionMenu(master, variable, default=None, *values, **kwargs)

  Themed OptionMenu, based after tkinter's OptionMenu, which allows
  the user to select a value from a menu.

  Method resolution order:
      OptionMenu
      Menubutton
      Widget
      tkinter.Widget
      tkinter.BaseWidget
      tkinter.Misc
      tkinter.Pack
      tkinter.Place
      tkinter.Grid
      builtins.object

  Methods defined here:

  __getitem__(self, item)
      Return the resource value for a KEY given as string.

  __init__(self, master, variable, default=None, *values, **kwargs)
      Construct a themed OptionMenu widget with master as the parent,
      the resource textvariable set to variable, the initially selected
      value specified by the default parameter, the menu values given by
      *values and additional keywords.

      WIDGET-SPECIFIC OPTIONS

          style: stylename
              Menubutton style.
          direction: 'above', 'below', 'left', 'right', or 'flush'
              Menubutton direction.
          command: callback
              A callback that will be invoked after selecting an item.

  destroy(self)
      Destroy this widget and its associated variable.

  set_menu(self, default=None, *values)
      Build a new menu of radiobuttons with *values and optionally
      a default value.

  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Methods inherited from Widget:

  identify(self, x, y)
      Returns the name of the element at position x, y, or the empty
      string if the point does not lie within any element.

      x and y are pixel coordinates relative to the widget.

  instate(self, statespec, callback=None, *args, **kw)
      Test the widget's state.

      If callback is not specified, returns True if the widget state
      matches statespec and False otherwise. If callback is specified,
      then it will be invoked with *args, **kw if the widget state
      matches statespec. statespec is expected to be a sequence.

  state(self, statespec=None)
      Modify or inquire widget state.

      Widget state is returned if statespec is None, otherwise it is
      set according to the statespec flags and then a new state spec
      is returned indicating which flags were changed. statespec is
      expected to be a sequence.

  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Methods inherited from tkinter.Misc:

  __repr__(self)
      Return repr(self).

  __setitem__(self, key, value)

  __str__(self)
      Return the window path name of this widget.

  after(self, ms, func=None, *args)
      Call function once after given time.

      MS specifies the time in milliseconds. FUNC gives the
      function which shall be called. Additional parameters
      are given as parameters to the function call.  Return
      identifier to cancel scheduling with after_cancel.

  after_cancel(self, id)
      Cancel scheduling of function identified with ID.

      Identifier returned by after or after_idle must be
      given as first parameter.

  after_idle(self, func, *args)
      Call FUNC once if the Tcl main loop has no event to
      process.

      Return an identifier to cancel the scheduling with
      after_cancel.

  anchor = grid_anchor(self, anchor=None)

  bbox = grid_bbox(self, column=None, row=None, col2=None, row2=None)

  bell(self, displayof=0)
      Ring a display's bell.

  bind(self, sequence=None, func=None, add=None)
      Bind to this widget at event SEQUENCE a call to function FUNC.

      SEQUENCE is a string of concatenated event
      patterns. An event pattern is of the form
      <MODIFIER-MODIFIER-TYPE-DETAIL> where MODIFIER is one
      of Control, Mod2, M2, Shift, Mod3, M3, Lock, Mod4, M4,
      Button1, B1, Mod5, M5 Button2, B2, Meta, M, Button3,
      B3, Alt, Button4, B4, Double, Button5, B5 Triple,
      Mod1, M1. TYPE is one of Activate, Enter, Map,
      ButtonPress, Button, Expose, Motion, ButtonRelease
      FocusIn, MouseWheel, Circulate, FocusOut, Property,
      Colormap, Gravity Reparent, Configure, KeyPress, Key,
      Unmap, Deactivate, KeyRelease Visibility, Destroy,
      Leave and DETAIL is the button number for ButtonPress,
      ButtonRelease and DETAIL is the Keysym for KeyPress and
      KeyRelease. Examples are
      <Control-Button-1> for pressing Control and mouse button 1 or
      <Alt-A> for pressing A and the Alt key (KeyPress can be omitted).
      An event pattern can also be a virtual event of the form
      <<AString>> where AString can be arbitrary. This
      event can be generated by event_generate.
      If events are concatenated they must appear shortly
      after each other.

      FUNC will be called if the event sequence occurs with an
      instance of Event as argument. If the return value of FUNC is
      "break" no further bound function is invoked.

      An additional boolean parameter ADD specifies whether FUNC will
      be called additionally to the other bound function or whether
      it will replace the previous function.

      Bind will return an identifier to allow deletion of the bound function with
      unbind without memory leak.

      If FUNC or SEQUENCE is omitted the bound function or list
      of bound events are returned.

  bind_all(self, sequence=None, func=None, add=None)
      Bind to all widgets at an event SEQUENCE a call to function FUNC.
      An additional boolean parameter ADD specifies whether FUNC will
      be called additionally to the other bound function or whether
      it will replace the previous function. See bind for the return value.

  bind_class(self, className, sequence=None, func=None, add=None)
      Bind to widgets with bindtag CLASSNAME at event
      SEQUENCE a call of function FUNC. An additional
      boolean parameter ADD specifies whether FUNC will be
      called additionally to the other bound function or
      whether it will replace the previous function. See bind for
      the return value.

  bindtags(self, tagList=None)
      Set or get the list of bindtags for this widget.

      With no argument return the list of all bindtags associated with
      this widget. With a list of strings as argument the bindtags are
      set to this list. The bindtags determine in which order events are
      processed (see bind).

  cget(self, key)
      Return the resource value for a KEY given as string.

  clipboard_append(self, string, **kw)
      Append STRING to the Tk clipboard.

      A widget specified at the optional displayof keyword
      argument specifies the target display. The clipboard
      can be retrieved with selection_get.

  clipboard_clear(self, **kw)
      Clear the data in the Tk clipboard.

      A widget specified for the optional displayof keyword
      argument specifies the target display.

  clipboard_get(self, **kw)
      Retrieve data from the clipboard on window's display.

      The window keyword defaults to the root window of the Tkinter
      application.

      The type keyword specifies the form in which the data is
      to be returned and should be an atom name such as STRING
      or FILE_NAME.  Type defaults to STRING, except on X11, where the default
      is to try UTF8_STRING and fall back to STRING.

      This command is equivalent to:

      selection_get(CLIPBOARD)

  columnconfigure = grid_columnconfigure(self, index, cnf={}, **kw)

  config = configure(self, cnf=None, **kw)

  configure(self, cnf=None, **kw)
      Configure resources of a widget.

      The values for resources are specified as keyword
      arguments. To get an overview about
      the allowed keyword arguments call the method keys.

  deletecommand(self, name)
      Internal function.

      Delete the Tcl command provided in NAME.

  event_add(self, virtual, *sequences)
      Bind a virtual event VIRTUAL (of the form <<Name>>)
      to an event SEQUENCE such that the virtual event is triggered
      whenever SEQUENCE occurs.

  event_delete(self, virtual, *sequences)
      Unbind a virtual event VIRTUAL from SEQUENCE.

  event_generate(self, sequence, **kw)
      Generate an event SEQUENCE. Additional
      keyword arguments specify parameter of the event
      (e.g. x, y, rootx, rooty).

  event_info(self, virtual=None)
      Return a list of all virtual events or the information
      about the SEQUENCE bound to the virtual event VIRTUAL.

  focus = focus_set(self)

  focus_displayof(self)
      Return the widget which has currently the focus on the
      display where this widget is located.

      Return None if the application does not have the focus.

  focus_force(self)
      Direct input focus to this widget even if the
      application does not have the focus. Use with
      caution!

  focus_get(self)
      Return the widget which has currently the focus in the
      application.

      Use focus_displayof to allow working with several
      displays. Return None if application does not have
      the focus.

  focus_lastfor(self)
      Return the widget which would have the focus if top level
      for this widget gets the focus from the window manager.

  focus_set(self)
      Direct input focus to this widget.

      If the application currently does not have the focus
      this widget will get the focus if the application gets
      the focus through the window manager.

  getboolean(self, s)
      Return a boolean value for Tcl boolean values true and false given as parameter.

  getdouble(self, s)

  getint(self, s)

  getvar(self, name='PY_VAR')
      Return value of Tcl variable NAME.

  grab_current(self)
      Return widget which has currently the grab in this application
      or None.

  grab_release(self)
      Release grab for this widget if currently set.

  grab_set(self)
      Set grab for this widget.

      A grab directs all events to this and descendant
      widgets in the application.

  grab_set_global(self)
      Set global grab for this widget.

      A global grab directs all events to this and
      descendant widgets on the display. Use with caution -
      other applications do not get events anymore.

  grab_status(self)
      Return None, "local" or "global" if this widget has
      no, a local or a global grab.

  grid_anchor(self, anchor=None)
      The anchor value controls how to place the grid within the
      master when no row/column has any weight.

      The default anchor is nw.

  grid_bbox(self, column=None, row=None, col2=None, row2=None)
      Return a tuple of integer coordinates for the bounding
      box of this widget controlled by the geometry manager grid.

      If COLUMN, ROW is given the bounding box applies from
      the cell with row and column 0 to the specified
      cell. If COL2 and ROW2 are given the bounding box
      starts at that cell.

      The returned integers specify the offset of the upper left
      corner in the master widget and the width and height.

  grid_columnconfigure(self, index, cnf={}, **kw)
      Configure column INDEX of a grid.

      Valid resources are minsize (minimum size of the column),
      weight (how much does additional space propagate to this column)
      and pad (how much space to let additionally).

  grid_location(self, x, y)
      Return a tuple of column and row which identify the cell
      at which the pixel at position X and Y inside the master
      widget is located.

  grid_propagate(self, flag=['_noarg_'])
      Set or get the status for propagation of geometry information.

      A boolean argument specifies whether the geometry information
      of the slaves will determine the size of this widget. If no argument
      is given, the current setting will be returned.

  grid_rowconfigure(self, index, cnf={}, **kw)
      Configure row INDEX of a grid.

      Valid resources are minsize (minimum size of the row),
      weight (how much does additional space propagate to this row)
      and pad (how much space to let additionally).

  grid_size(self)
      Return a tuple of the number of column and rows in the grid.

  grid_slaves(self, row=None, column=None)
      Return a list of all slaves of this widget
      in its packing order.

  image_names(self)
      Return a list of all existing image names.

  image_types(self)
      Return a list of all available image types (e.g. photo bitmap).

  keys(self)
      Return a list of all resource names of this widget.

  lift = tkraise(self, aboveThis=None)

  lower(self, belowThis=None)
      Lower this widget in the stacking order.

  mainloop(self, n=0)
      Call the mainloop of Tk.

  nametowidget(self, name)
      Return the Tkinter instance of a widget identified by
      its Tcl name NAME.

  option_add(self, pattern, value, priority=None)
      Set a VALUE (second parameter) for an option
      PATTERN (first parameter).

      An optional third parameter gives the numeric priority
      (defaults to 80).

  option_clear(self)
      Clear the option database.

      It will be reloaded if option_add is called.

  option_get(self, name, className)
      Return the value for an option NAME for this widget
      with CLASSNAME.

      Values with higher priority override lower values.

  option_readfile(self, fileName, priority=None)
      Read file FILENAME into the option database.

      An optional second parameter gives the numeric
      priority.

  pack_propagate(self, flag=['_noarg_'])
      Set or get the status for propagation of geometry information.

      A boolean argument specifies whether the geometry information
      of the slaves will determine the size of this widget. If no argument
      is given the current setting will be returned.

  pack_slaves(self)
      Return a list of all slaves of this widget
      in its packing order.

  place_slaves(self)
      Return a list of all slaves of this widget
      in its packing order.

  propagate = pack_propagate(self, flag=['_noarg_'])

  quit(self)
      Quit the Tcl interpreter. All widgets will be destroyed.

  register = _register(self, func, subst=None, needcleanup=1)

  rowconfigure = grid_rowconfigure(self, index, cnf={}, **kw)

  selection_clear(self, **kw)
      Clear the current X selection.

  selection_get(self, **kw)
      Return the contents of the current X selection.

      A keyword parameter selection specifies the name of
      the selection and defaults to PRIMARY.  A keyword
      parameter displayof specifies a widget on the display
      to use. A keyword parameter type specifies the form of data to be
      fetched, defaulting to STRING except on X11, where UTF8_STRING is tried
      before STRING.

  selection_handle(self, command, **kw)
      Specify a function COMMAND to call if the X
      selection owned by this widget is queried by another
      application.

      This function must return the contents of the
      selection. The function will be called with the
      arguments OFFSET and LENGTH which allows the chunking
      of very long selections. The following keyword
      parameters can be provided:
      selection - name of the selection (default PRIMARY),
      type - type of the selection (e.g. STRING, FILE_NAME).

  selection_own(self, **kw)
      Become owner of X selection.

      A keyword parameter selection specifies the name of
      the selection (default PRIMARY).

  selection_own_get(self, **kw)
      Return owner of X selection.

      The following keyword parameter can
      be provided:
      selection - name of the selection (default PRIMARY),
      type - type of the selection (e.g. STRING, FILE_NAME).

  send(self, interp, cmd, *args)
      Send Tcl command CMD to different interpreter INTERP to be executed.

  setvar(self, name='PY_VAR', value='1')
      Set Tcl variable NAME to VALUE.

  size = grid_size(self)

  slaves = pack_slaves(self)

  tk_bisque(self)
      Change the color scheme to light brown as used in Tk 3.6 and before.

  tk_focusFollowsMouse(self)
      The widget under mouse will get automatically focus. Can not
      be disabled easily.

  tk_focusNext(self)
      Return the next widget in the focus order which follows
      widget which has currently the focus.

      The focus order first goes to the next child, then to
      the children of the child recursively and then to the
      next sibling which is higher in the stacking order.  A
      widget is omitted if it has the takefocus resource set
      to 0.

  tk_focusPrev(self)
      Return previous widget in the focus order. See tk_focusNext for details.

  tk_setPalette(self, *args, **kw)
      Set a new color scheme for all widget elements.

      A single color as argument will cause that all colors of Tk
      widget elements are derived from this.
      Alternatively several keyword parameters and its associated
      colors can be given. The following keywords are valid:
      activeBackground, foreground, selectColor,
      activeForeground, highlightBackground, selectBackground,
      background, highlightColor, selectForeground,
      disabledForeground, insertBackground, troughColor.

  tk_strictMotif(self, boolean=None)
      Set Tcl internal variable, whether the look and feel
      should adhere to Motif.

      A parameter of 1 means adhere to Motif (e.g. no color
      change if mouse passes over slider).
      Returns the set value.

  tkraise(self, aboveThis=None)
      Raise this widget in the stacking order.

  unbind(self, sequence, funcid=None)
      Unbind for this widget for event SEQUENCE  the
      function identified with FUNCID.

  unbind_all(self, sequence)
      Unbind for all widgets for event SEQUENCE all functions.

  unbind_class(self, className, sequence)
      Unbind for all widgets with bindtag CLASSNAME for event SEQUENCE
      all functions.

  update(self)
      Enter event loop until all pending events have been processed by Tcl.

  update_idletasks(self)
      Enter event loop until all idle callbacks have been called. This
      will update the display of windows but not process events caused by
      the user.

  wait_variable(self, name='PY_VAR')
      Wait until the variable is modified.

      A parameter of type IntVar, StringVar, DoubleVar or
      BooleanVar must be given.

  wait_visibility(self, window=None)
      Wait until the visibility of a WIDGET changes
      (e.g. it appears).

      If no parameter is given self is used.

  wait_window(self, window=None)
      Wait until a WIDGET is destroyed.

      If no parameter is given self is used.

  waitvar = wait_variable(self, name='PY_VAR')

  winfo_atom(self, name, displayof=0)
      Return integer which represents atom NAME.

  winfo_atomname(self, id, displayof=0)
      Return name of atom with identifier ID.

  winfo_cells(self)
      Return number of cells in the colormap for this widget.

  winfo_children(self)
      Return a list of all widgets which are children of this widget.

  winfo_class(self)
      Return window class name of this widget.

  winfo_colormapfull(self)
      Return True if at the last color request the colormap was full.

  winfo_containing(self, rootX, rootY, displayof=0)
      Return the widget which is at the root coordinates ROOTX, ROOTY.

  winfo_depth(self)
      Return the number of bits per pixel.

  winfo_exists(self)
      Return true if this widget exists.

  winfo_fpixels(self, number)
      Return the number of pixels for the given distance NUMBER
      (e.g. "3c") as float.

  winfo_geometry(self)
      Return geometry string for this widget in the form "widthxheight+X+Y".

  winfo_height(self)
      Return height of this widget.

  winfo_id(self)
      Return identifier ID for this widget.

  winfo_interps(self, displayof=0)
      Return the name of all Tcl interpreters for this display.

  winfo_ismapped(self)
      Return true if this widget is mapped.

  winfo_manager(self)
      Return the window manager name for this widget.

  winfo_name(self)
      Return the name of this widget.

  winfo_parent(self)
      Return the name of the parent of this widget.

  winfo_pathname(self, id, displayof=0)
      Return the pathname of the widget given by ID.

  winfo_pixels(self, number)
      Rounded integer value of winfo_fpixels.

  winfo_pointerx(self)
      Return the x coordinate of the pointer on the root window.

  winfo_pointerxy(self)
      Return a tuple of x and y coordinates of the pointer on the root window.

  winfo_pointery(self)
      Return the y coordinate of the pointer on the root window.

  winfo_reqheight(self)
      Return requested height of this widget.

  winfo_reqwidth(self)
      Return requested width of this widget.

  winfo_rgb(self, color)
      Return a tuple of integer RGB values in range(65536) for color in this widget.

  winfo_rootx(self)
      Return x coordinate of upper left corner of this widget on the
      root window.

  winfo_rooty(self)
      Return y coordinate of upper left corner of this widget on the
      root window.

  winfo_screen(self)
      Return the screen name of this widget.

  winfo_screencells(self)
      Return the number of the cells in the colormap of the screen
      of this widget.

  winfo_screendepth(self)
      Return the number of bits per pixel of the root window of the
      screen of this widget.

  winfo_screenheight(self)
      Return the number of pixels of the height of the screen of this widget
      in pixel.

  winfo_screenmmheight(self)
      Return the number of pixels of the height of the screen of
      this widget in mm.

  winfo_screenmmwidth(self)
      Return the number of pixels of the width of the screen of
      this widget in mm.

  winfo_screenvisual(self)
      Return one of the strings directcolor, grayscale, pseudocolor,
      staticcolor, staticgray, or truecolor for the default
      colormodel of this screen.

  winfo_screenwidth(self)
      Return the number of pixels of the width of the screen of
      this widget in pixel.

  winfo_server(self)
      Return information of the X-Server of the screen of this widget in
      the form "XmajorRminor vendor vendorVersion".

  winfo_toplevel(self)
      Return the toplevel widget of this widget.

  winfo_viewable(self)
      Return true if the widget and all its higher ancestors are mapped.

  winfo_visual(self)
      Return one of the strings directcolor, grayscale, pseudocolor,
      staticcolor, staticgray, or truecolor for the
      colormodel of this widget.

  winfo_visualid(self)
      Return the X identifier for the visual for this widget.

  winfo_visualsavailable(self, includeids=False)
      Return a list of all visuals available for the screen
      of this widget.

      Each item in the list consists of a visual name (see winfo_visual), a
      depth and if includeids is true is given also the X identifier.

  winfo_vrootheight(self)
      Return the height of the virtual root window associated with this
      widget in pixels. If there is no virtual root window return the
      height of the screen.

  winfo_vrootwidth(self)
      Return the width of the virtual root window associated with this
      widget in pixel. If there is no virtual root window return the
      width of the screen.

  winfo_vrootx(self)
      Return the x offset of the virtual root relative to the root
      window of the screen of this widget.

  winfo_vrooty(self)
      Return the y offset of the virtual root relative to the root
      window of the screen of this widget.

  winfo_width(self)
      Return the width of this widget.

  winfo_x(self)
      Return the x coordinate of the upper left corner of this widget
      in the parent.

  winfo_y(self)
      Return the y coordinate of the upper left corner of this widget
      in the parent.

  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Data descriptors inherited from tkinter.Misc:

  __dict__
      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)

  __weakref__
      list of weak references to the object (if defined)

  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Methods inherited from tkinter.Pack:

  forget = pack_forget(self)

  info = pack_info(self)

  pack = pack_configure(self, cnf={}, **kw)

  pack_configure(self, cnf={}, **kw)
      Pack a widget in the parent widget. Use as options:
      after=widget - pack it after you have packed widget
      anchor=NSEW (or subset) - position widget according to
                                given direction
      before=widget - pack it before you will pack widget
      expand=bool - expand widget if parent size grows
      fill=NONE or X or Y or BOTH - fill widget if widget grows
      in=master - use master to contain this widget
      in_=master - see 'in' option description
      ipadx=amount - add internal padding in x direction
      ipady=amount - add internal padding in y direction
      padx=amount - add padding in x direction
      pady=amount - add padding in y direction
      side=TOP or BOTTOM or LEFT or RIGHT -  where to add this widget.

  pack_forget(self)
      Unmap this widget and do not use it for the packing order.

  pack_info(self)
      Return information about the packing options
      for this widget.

  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Methods inherited from tkinter.Place:

  place = place_configure(self, cnf={}, **kw)

  place_configure(self, cnf={}, **kw)
      Place a widget in the parent widget. Use as options:
      in=master - master relative to which the widget is placed
      in_=master - see 'in' option description
      x=amount - locate anchor of this widget at position x of master
      y=amount - locate anchor of this widget at position y of master
      relx=amount - locate anchor of this widget between 0.0 and 1.0
                    relative to width of master (1.0 is right edge)
      rely=amount - locate anchor of this widget between 0.0 and 1.0
                    relative to height of master (1.0 is bottom edge)
      anchor=NSEW (or subset) - position anchor according to given direction
      width=amount - width of this widget in pixel
      height=amount - height of this widget in pixel
      relwidth=amount - width of this widget between 0.0 and 1.0
                        relative to width of master (1.0 is the same width
                        as the master)
      relheight=amount - height of this widget between 0.0 and 1.0
                         relative to height of master (1.0 is the same
                         height as the master)
      bordermode="inside" or "outside" - whether to take border width of
                                         master widget into account

  place_forget(self)
      Unmap this widget.

  place_info(self)
      Return information about the placing options
      for this widget.

  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Methods inherited from tkinter.Grid:

  grid = grid_configure(self, cnf={}, **kw)

  grid_configure(self, cnf={}, **kw)
      Position a widget in the parent widget in a grid. Use as options:
      column=number - use cell identified with given column (starting with 0)
      columnspan=number - this widget will span several columns
      in=master - use master to contain this widget
      in_=master - see 'in' option description
      ipadx=amount - add internal padding in x direction
      ipady=amount - add internal padding in y direction
      padx=amount - add padding in x direction
      pady=amount - add padding in y direction
      row=number - use cell identified with given row (starting with 0)
      rowspan=number - this widget will span several rows
      sticky=NSEW - if cell is larger on which sides will this
                    widget stick to the cell boundary

  grid_forget(self)
      Unmap this widget.

  grid_info(self)
      Return information about the options
      for positioning this widget in a grid.

  grid_remove(self)
      Unmap this widget but remember the grid options.

  location = grid_location(self, x, y)
```